# No se carga una imagen en BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy tratando de cargar imágenes en tiempo de ejecución y cada una se selecciona por medio de un switch:

```
seguimiento.tareaA = new Image();
switch (rowTarea["idTareaTipo"].ToString())
                    {
                        case "f7f91a6f-24a2-1034-b505-d1f8671a4f3f"://Seguimiento
                            Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Seguim_Chico__0000_6_Pago_Rojo.png");
                            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(uri);
                            seguimiento.tareaA.Source = bmp;
                            break;
```

Al momento de correr el programa, no da errores pero tampoco se cargan las imágenes... 
Trate de debuggear y lo único extraño que encontré fue un error en el Metadata al crear el BitmapImage:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo solucionar el error o hacer que se muestre la imagen?

Comment: Te está dando una excepción, podrías compartir el texto de la excepción?
'System.NotSuppor...'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En algún momento tuve ese problema y encontre un post en el [SO original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1651397/3100840)

El truco es poner el origen entre los metodos `BeginInit()` y `EndInit()`

```
BitmapImage logo = new BitmapImage();
logo.BeginInit();
logo.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Resources/logo.png");
logo.EndInit();
```

La explicación esta en la [documentación oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.begininit(v=vs.110).aspx):

> La inicialización de la propiedad debe realizarse entre las llamadas
>   BeginInit y EndInit. Una vez que se ha inicializado BitmapImage, los
>   cambios de propiedad se ignoran.

Comment: Agregando esas lineas me da el siguiente error: **No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'AssemblyName, Culture=neutral' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado** y debugueando en metadata esta igual

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
seguimiento.tareaA = new Image();
switch (rowTarea["idTareaTipo"].ToString())
{
    case "f7f91a6f-24a2-1034-b505-d1f8671a4f3f"://Seguimiento
    BitmapImage bi3 = new BitmapImage();
    bi3.BeginInit();
    bi3.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Seguim_Chico__0000_6_Pago_Rojo.png");
    bi3.EndInit();
    seguimiento.tareaA.Source = bi3;
    break;
```